# xonsh + kitty and disappearing text

Tags: terminal, xonsh

Maximizing and restoring kitty terminal window, makes xonsh output from previous commands disappear. Any way to fix it? This doesn't happen in different shells (fish/bash).

Example:

Before:

[image]

After maximizing and restoring the window:

[image]

I noticed that it doesn't actually disappear forever, but xonsh somehow inserts a lot of empty lines so I need to scroll about a full screen to see the output, that was visibile before maximize/restore.

Also switching Xonsh from prompt_toolkit to readline solves the problem, so it seems to be connected with prompt_toolkit.

I use:

- shell: xonsh 0.11.0
- terminal: kitty 0.24.1
- Linux Manjaro KDE

---